# Chrome Cross Document Messaging Not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have following two pages and I am trying to send message from the main page to an iframe inside it. It is working correctly in IE 11 **but not on Chrome**. I don't see the pop-up or the console message in Chrome browser. The Chrome browser version is 60.0.3112.113.

HtmlPage1.html - `http://localhost/Htmlpage1.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="root">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Sheep</title>
</head>
<body id="b">
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://localhost/HtmlPage2.html" height="200" width="300" seamless></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var myFrame = window.document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow;
            myFrame.postMessage("A cow", "*");
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

HtmlPage2.html - `http://localhost/Htmlpage2.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Drococile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Fat Sheep :D</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            alert(event.data);
            console.log(event.data);
        }, false);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix is to wait for the iframe to load

```
    var myFrame = window.document.getElementById("myFrame");
    myFrame.onload=function() {
        myFrame.contentWindow.postMessage("A cow", "*");
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, that works correctly. Chrome is too fast :D.

Comment: actually, it's because chrome is too slow loading the iframe :p

Comment: Oh true. It's the other way :D. In chrome, it was trying to post the message to the iFrame before the iFrame was loaded.